# php checking if the last character is a '/' if not then tack it on

Tags: php

I have these 2 snippets of code that I have been playing with, but can't seem to get the logic to stick in either of them.

I am trying to see if a given string has a '/' at the end, if not then add it.

`$path = '.';`

```
if (substr($path, 0, -1) != '/')
    $path .= '/';
```

and

```
if (strrpos('/', $path) !== true)
    $path .= '/';
```

the issue im having is that if i make `$path` equal to `'./` then I get this as the output `.//`

this is the snippet of where i am having the issue

```
if (!is_array($paths))
    $this->classPath[] = $paths;
else
    $this->classPath = $paths;

foreach ($this->classPath as $path) {

    if (strrpos('/', $path) !== true)// || substr_count($path, '/') >= 0)
        $path = $path . '/';
    //else
        //$this->classPath[] = $path;
        //echo '0';
    $pathArr[] = $path;
```

Comment: you have that issue with both codes or only with latter one? what's the point in using latter one at all?

Comment: to both. and i was am trying to detect if the last string is `/` the both one should iterate from the last string right?

Comment: I think you want `strrpos('/', $path) !== 0`

Comment: @knittl the syntax for `strrpos` is wrong, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php, also it won't return 0 but last char's position if it's a `/`.

Comment: You could use `strpos(strrev($path), '/') !== 0`

Comment: @dotoree: You are totally correct :)

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You might be overthinking it. While the `substr()` method will work perfectly it might be simpler to use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) to remove any trailing slashes and then add one on.

```
$path = rtrim($path, '/') . '/';
```

Caution: this will trim multiple trailing forward slashes. so `.//////` becomes `./`

Comment: Suggestion: use `rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead, to keep it platform neutral.

Comment: @ChrisBaker Beware on using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for URLs as it will not output the correct ones.

Answer (score 5):

My solution: simple and even converts back slashes, useful for windows developers:

```
function fixpath($p) {
    $p=str_replace('\\','/',trim($p));
    return (substr($p,-1)!='/') ? $p.='/' : $p;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try to use this function

```
    function endsWith($FullStr, $needle)
    {
        $StrLen = strlen($needle);
        $FullStrEnd = substr($FullStr, strlen($FullStr) - $StrLen);
        return $FullStrEnd == $needle;
    }
```

taken from my [blog post](http://jaspreetchahal.org/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions/)

then use it like

```
if (endsWith($path,'/') == false) 
{
    $path = $path."/";
}
```

and offcourse if you do not want to use above function to siplify things then you should change the way you are using substr

correct way to get last char is `substr($path,-1)`

Comment: your foot is good bro! The function simply easify `substr` function so that you don't really have to re-think the logic for `substr`. Just to prove your point you can not be that rude. the above is an option. You can always use `substr` whenever you like

Comment: If you're doing `strlen($FullStr)`, you might as well do `strlen($needle)` and save a line. Or make two variables if you like – just keep it consistent

Answer (score 1):

You are just using substr wrong.

To get the last character you have just use negative offset: `substr($path,-1)`

Your code lacks 2 **fundamental things**, essential for the programming:

- debugging
- documentation reading.

Debugging is as simple as just echoing your variables.
by echoing `substr($path, 0, -1)` you can make yourself aware that your code is somewhat wrong and by reading [documentation](http://php.net/substr) you can see the right usage.

Comment: im past the debugging stage, as probably 90% of people on stackoverflow are, i came here seeking for a second opinion as to how my logic is lacking.

Comment: One does not simply "pass" the debugging stage :)

Comment: "i am past" what? what the heck is "debugging stage"?

Comment: You debug all the time. You never stop debugging, with the sole exception of your death. You can never be "past" the debugging stage.

Answer (score 0):

you can also get a count of number of characters in a string by function strlen()

and for loop over and access, every index in string and do check if this index === '/'

do something like

```
$string = 'test/';
$countString = strlen($string);

for($i=0;$i < $countString;$i++){

    if ($string[$i] === '/'){
        echo 'yes string had /';
        die;
    }
}
```