# dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) how to return bar correctly?

Tags: php, url

```
$path = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
$path .=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]. dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
```

I have this and this is what happens if I make a echo

```
echo $path
http:://localhost/folder
```

and without folder

```
http:://localhost/
```

if there is a folder not return my bar if I attached a bar as well the result without folder so

```
$path .=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]. dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/";
echo $path
http:://localhost/folder
http:://localhost//
```

any idea better or more optimal to get what I want?
to give me a single bar in the two cases

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339619/php-checking-if-the-last-character-is-a-if-not-then-tack-it-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, by `bar` you actually mean `/` or the `forward slash` character, and that when the `dirname()` returns nothing, you end up with `//` but would like only a single `/`.

If this is the case, then the following should satisfy what you are looking for.

```
$path = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/' . trim(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]),'/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rtrim($path, '/')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to trim any `/` from back of url.