# Cannot enable the Google Calendar Cloud API

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I spoke with Google Workspace customer support and they failed to find appropriate documentation about this issue.  They directed me here.

Very simply, I'm trying to enable the Google Cloud API to create an event in a user's calendar (and hopefully adding a Google Meet URL to it) as per this document: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events.

I am following the Quickstart PHP code sample which first instructs to install the SDK via composer and authorize the Google Cloud API in PHP.  That link is here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php.

The script (Step 2) provided by that page initially failed (during Step 3) with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: file "credentials.json" does not exist in /path/to/vendor/Google/google/apiclient/src/Client.php:984
```

Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/app_root/quickstart.php(17): Google\Client->setAuthConfig('credentials.jso...')
#1 /path/to/app_root/quickstart.php(63): getClient()
#2 {main}
thrown in /path/to/vendor/Google/google/apiclient/src/Client.php on line 984

I have created a service account as per the instruction here:

Although the instructions did not include steps to create a service account and generate JSON keys, I found that solution online, and it was verified by the Google Workspace support agent.  I downloaded and renamed that file and put it in the script root directory (although the path was not specified in the incomplete documentation either, this was verified by the Google Workspace support agent).  I ran the script again and received this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redirect URI in /path/to/vendor/Google/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php:694
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/vendor/Google/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(406): Google\Auth\OAuth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(Array)
#1 /path/to/app_root/quickstart.php(38): Google\Client->createAuthUrl()
#2 /path/to/app_root/quickstart.php(63): getClient()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/vendor/Google/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php on line 694
```

I have tried to create an OAuth redirect URI and regenerated the JSON keys, however, the same error occurred.  Here is the authentication JSON file that I downloaded from the service account **KEYS** section with any account specific information redacted:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "massive-clone-{REDACTED}",
  "private_key_id": "{REDACTED}",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----{REDACTED}\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "calendar-api@massive-clone-{REDACTED}.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "{REDACTED}",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/calendar-api%40massive-clone-{REDACTED}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Although the quickstart guide seems to address this issue in the troubleshooting section, the advise does not seem to apply since there is no "button" in Step 1. From the troubleshooting section:

> **Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redirect URI**
>
> This error occurs when the credentials.json file used contains a
> client ID of the wrong type. This code requires an OAuth client ID of
> type Other, which will be created for you when using the button in
> Step 1. If creating your own client ID please ensure you select the
> correct type.

Can anyone help me understand how to get the appropriate `credentials.json` file?  I'm not sure about how this process is supposed to go, but the Google Workspace support agent said they could not find any documentation and directed me here.  If my question needs to be specified in an different way, please advise.

Comment: It seems this issue is common and the [quickstart troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php#uncaught_invalidargumentexception_missing_the_required_redirect_uri) says this is caused by a wrong client ID type. Have you tried to do the suggestion to use the correct type of OAuth client ID, **Other**?

Comment: I modified the OP to explain why the troubleshooting section is useless for this error.  There is no button in Step 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710171/17842569, this might help. There is also another answer there where it uses a PHP client library. You might also want to consider it.

Comment: You are using a service account. The example uses OAuth Client. secrets: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer @JohnHanley so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to use a service account. The example uses use OAuth Client Secrets.

[Setting up OAuth 2.0](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en)